# Orthonormal Basis of Hermitian matrices for a Hilbert Space of Operators

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Consider a set of operators $O$ on a Hilbert space $V$ of dimension $d$.
I could prove that $O$ is also a Hilbert space with dimension $d^2$ (inner product being $(A,B) = tr(A^\dagger B))$. 
Now I am trying to find an orthonormal basis of Hermitian matrices for the space of $O$.
However I am not sure how to proceed, also cant understand how Gram-Schmidt can help here.

Comment: you know that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^d$?

Comment: @user251257 I dont understand how that helps.

Comment: Do you know a basis for hermitian matrices?

Comment: @user251257 Nope! I am not sure we are on the same page. I am trying to find an orthonormal basis for $O$, which constitutes of only Hermitian matrices.

Comment: Once you have a basis you can obtain an orthonormal one. Btw. The set of complex hermitian matrices is not a complex vector space. However it is a real one.